# How to print "image x tapped" when user taps on one of many UIImages in the View Controller? (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a set of 12 UIImageViews in my storyboard, and, for argument's sake, I want to get each one to print to logs "You just tapped image x", when the user taps on it, where x is the number of image tapped, from 1-12). So i need to detect which image is tapped, and do something depending on that information. What would be the best way to do this, in Swift 3 ?

(I assume 12 IBActions -treat them as button with an image on background- is really bad code. Also they need to be placed on specific positions on top of a background image, so cannot use UICollectionView to do this.) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think using a collectionView is a better approach to achieve what do you want. However, you'll need to:

- Set `userInteractionEnabled` to `true` for all of your imageViews.
- Set -sequential- `tag` for all of your imageViews, for example image1.tag = 1, image2.tag = 2 ... and so on.
- Implement a method to be the target of all of your images tapping, it should be similar to this:

  `func imageViewTapped(imageView: UIImageView) {
      print("You just tapped image (imageView.tag)")
  }`
- Create -one single- tap gesture and assign the implemented method to its selector:

`let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageViewTapped))`

- Finally, add the `tapGesture` for all of your image, for example: image1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture), image2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)... and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I tried it out but nothing happens when i tap the images. I have set up tags,userInteraction=yes, and referencing outlets from UIImages to the TapGestureRecognizer in Storyboard. When i programmatically add image1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture), image2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture), and so on, then it only works on the last one, ignoring the prior ones. Any ideas what could be wrong?  I am on a very beginner level with coding so could be something simple. I'll keep working on it - thanks again

Comment: An update, have finally made it work - the only way it worked was , as per your solution above, BUT, i had to make distinct tapGestureRecognizer instances for each image. If i did same one as per your solution, it only registered the last one, and tap recognition only worked on the last uiImageView to have tapGesture added to it. So i did something like this :

Comment: let tapGestureFirst = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(tap))
            let tapGestureTwo = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(tap))

Comment: followed by :

 firstImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureFirst)
            
secondImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureTwo)

and so on, for all 12 views

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad code per-se, but if you did it that way, or with tap gestures on each of the ImageViews you would likely want to separate out that part of the logic.

There are other approaches/views you could use to manage this kind of thing better, especially if this is supposed to scale, but with your constraints this is what I would suggest:

Either add TapGestureRecognizers to your imageViews or make them buttons, then connect all their actions to this:

```
@IBAction func phoneWasPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let tappedImageView = sender as? UIImageView else {
        return
    }

    switch tappedImageView {
    case imageView1:
        //do something
    case imageView2:
        // do something else
    //etc.
    default:
        break
    }
    switch sender
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - how would I connect the actions of the multiple TapGestureRecognizers to the IBaction you are referring to? I am quite a newbie so only way I know of connecting actions to a method is by IBAction ctrl-drag!

Comment: You can do that with GestureRecognizers as well with the selector, but take a look here: http://rshankar.com/uigesturerecognizer-in-swift/ https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer

Comment: Thank you sir - i will check it out

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bad idea at all to have 12 buttons. Assign each of them a tag from 1-12 and connect them to the same IBAction.

```
@IBAction func didTapImageButton(button: UIButton) {
    print("You just tapped image \(button.tag)")
}
```